# how to remove first and last \n from string? PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem in a variable in PHP that I want to remove the first and last \n from a string but not the \n in the text.

eg:

```
<--------------\n //I want to remove this (if exists)
some text \n
some text \n
<--------------\n //I want to remove this (if exists)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `trim()` your string

Comment: thank you! I thought trim would remove all \n...

Comment: Trim also remove spaces, tab spaces, and other, you should really look at [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim PHP function makes what you want to do : All whitespaces before and after string are removed.

```
$someText = "   bulbul   ";
echo trim($sometext); // "bulbul"
```

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` strips whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. I believe this is what you need. More on the trim() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php